# Javascript Form Validation - Checkbox from an array, first digit of input

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am having quite a few issues using java script to validate an application form.

1. validatePostCode: take the value from a selection box and depending on what is chosen, check if the first value of the post code matches the set validation. I tried .charAt(0) but it still displays an error message even if it is correct.
2. validateTextBox: if the "otherskills" checkbox is checked, the text box cannot be empty. as you can see in my html, my checkbox uses arrays but I don't know to get the value of only "otherskills"

thank you

```js
"use strict"; 
var errMsg = "";
/*get variables from form and check rules*/
function validate(){
var result = true; 

result = validateDOB() && validatePostCode() && validateTextBox() && validateJobReferenceNumber();

if (errMsg != ""){ //only display message box if there is something to show
 alert(errMsg);
 }

return result;
}

function validateDOB(){
var dob = document.forms["regForm"]["dob"].value;
var age = getAge(dob);
var error = document.getElementById("spanDob");
var pattern =/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
 if (dob == null || dob == "" || !pattern.test(dob) || age < 15 || age > 80) {
        error.textContent = "Please enter a valid date of birth\n";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function getAge(dob) { /* find age from today's date minus entered DOB*/
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dob);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

function validatePostCode(){
 var postcode = document.forms["regForm"]["postcode"].value;
 var state = document.forms["regForm"]["state"].value; 
 var error = document.getElementById("spanPostcode");
 switch (state){
  case "VIC":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 3 || postcode.charAt(0) !== 8){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for VIC";
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "NSW":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 1 || postcode.charAt(0) !== 2){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for NSW"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "QLD":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 4 || postcode.charAt(0) !== 9){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for QLD"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "NT":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 0){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for NT"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "WA":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 6){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for WA"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "SA":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 5){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for SA"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "TAS":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 7){
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for TAS"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  case "ACT":
  if (postcode.charAt(0) !== 0) {
   error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for ACT"
   return false;
  }
  break;
  default: 
  error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code";
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

function validateTextBox(){
 var checkboxOtherSkills = document.getElementById("skills[]").getElementsByTagName("input"); 
 var textbox = document.forms["regForm"]["otherSkills"].value;

 if (checkboxOtherSkills[oSkills].checked){
  if (textbox.length < 1){
   errMsg +="'Other Skills' has been selected but not filled out.";
   return false;
  }
 } 
 return true;
}

function validateJobReferenceNumber(){
 var refnumb = document.getElementById("jobrefno");
 var pattern = (/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){6}$/);

 if (!pattern.test(refnumb)){
  errMsg += "6 alphanumeric characters only";
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

function init(){
 var regForm = document.getElementById("regForm");// get ref to the HTML element
 regForm.onsubmit = validate; 
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form id="regForm" method="post" action="http://mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" novalidate="novalidate">
 <fieldset><legend>Application:</legend>

 <!--Job Reference Number-->
 <p><label for="jobrefno">Job Reference Number</label>
 <input type="text" name="jobrefno" id="jobrefno" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}" title="Must be 6 characters" required="required" /><span id="spanJobRefNo"></span></p>
 <!--First Name-->
 <p><label for="firstName">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+${1,25}" maxlength="25" title="Max Length 25" required="required" /><span id="spanFirstName"></span></p>
 <!--Last Name-->
 <p><label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+${1,25}" maxlength="25" title="Max Length 25" required="required" /><span id="spanLastName"></span></p>
 <!--Date of Birth-->
  <p><label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
 <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" required="required" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/><span id="spanDob"></span></p>
 <!--Gender-->
 <fieldset><legend>Gender</legend></span>
 <p><label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Unspecified" checked="checked"/>Prefer not to say</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male</label></p>
 <span id="spanGender"></fieldset> 
 <!--Street Address-->
 <p><label for="streetAddress">Street Address</label>
 <input type="text" name="streetAddress" id="streetAddress" maxlength="40" title="Max Length 40" required="required" /><span id="spanStreetAddress"></span></p>
 <!--Suburb-->
 <p><label for="suburb">Suburb</label>
 <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" maxlength="40" title="Max Length 40" required="required" /><span id="spanSuburb"></span></p>
 <!--State--> 
 <p><label for="state">State</label>
 <select required ="required" name="state" id="state">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
 <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
 <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
 <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
 <option value="NT">NT</option>
 <option value="WA">WA</option>
 <option value="SA">SA</option>
 <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
 <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
 </select>
 <span id="spanState"></span>
 </p>
 <!--Postcode-->
 <p><label for="postcode">PostCode</label>
 <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" title="4 Digits only" required="required" /><span id="spanPostcode"></span>
 <!--Email address-->
 <p><label for="email">Email</label>
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="youremail@host.com" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" title="Please use correct format: eg. mrburns@hotmail.com" required="required" /><span id="spanEmail"></span></p>
 <!--Phone Number-->
 <p><label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
 <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]+{8,12}" maxlength = "12" title="8-12 Digits" required="required" /><span id="spanPhoneNumber"></span>  
 </p>
 <!--Skill List-->
 <label>Skills List</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="HTML5" checked="checked" />HTML5</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="CSS" />CSS</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="JavaScript">JavaScript</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Excel" />Excel</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="MySQL" />MySQL</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Administration" />Administration</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="12MoExp" />12 Months Experience</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id ="oSkills" value="OtherSkills" />Other Skills...</label><br>
 <!--Other Skills-->
 <p><label for="otherSkills">Other Skills</label> <span id="spanOtherSkills"></span><br>
 <textarea id="otherSkills" name="otherSkills" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Please tell us about any other skills you have that may benefit you in this position"></textarea></p>
 </fieldset>
 <p>
 <input type= "submit" value="Apply"/>
 <input type= "reset" value="Reset Form"/></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> validatePostCode: take the value from a selection box and depending on
>   what is chosen, check if the first value of the post code matches the
>   set validation. I tried .charAt(0) but it still displays an error
>   message even if it is correct.

That's because you compare `postcode.charAt(0)` (which is a string) with a number. Instead of `postcode.charAt(0) !== 1` you can do `postcode.charAt(0) !== "1"` (note that `"1"` is also a string now)

---

Now about validateTextBox

Selector `document.getElementById("skills[]")` returns null, because there are no elements with id "skills[]".

Your desired checkbox has id "oSkills" so you can do this instead:
 `var checkboxOtherSkills = document.getElementById("oSkills");`

And then of course you would need to replace `if (checkboxOtherSkills[oSkills].checked)` with `if (checkboxOtherSkills.checked)`

Comment: validatePostCode: Unfortunately it still isn't working :( when i print state and postcode.charAt(0) it returns the correct data. thank you for trying though

validateTextBox: This worked perfectly! Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
case "VIC":
  if ( postcode.charAt(0) == 3 || postcode.charAt(0) == 8){
   error.textContent = "";
   return true;
  }
     else {
      error.textContent = "Please enter a valid post code for VIC";
         return false;
     }
  break;
```

I changed the conditions to return true if it fits, otherwise it returns false and the code works!